# Creating Backup .tar.gz with specific size

Tags: bash, flash, backup, archive

I am working on recovering a crashed (XWin crash) computer with over 280GB of data needing recovery.  I have CLI so need to write a script to create .tar.gz file on the 64GB flash I have, which has only 59G of available space, as it also must keep the BASH scripts being executed on the flash itself.

Any ideas on howto create "sized" archive files?  Have not found any thing close searching the inet.

Also it must track what has already been archived, because manually, when the flash is full, it will be removed to master server with 1TB backup drive where backups will be copied, then archive removed, re-inserted into the "recovery" machine and must continue from the last point in the backup process.

Ideally the backup will/would delete all files previously/successfully backed up, so no confusion on where the backup process actually is on the machine and if aborted, then would not restart at position zero (0).

Comment: Go buy an external USB hard drive. $100 will be worth less than the pain of trying to split, compress, and decompress.

Comment: agree about the external drive. What you describe is similar to full-fledged data backup/recovery systems that are person-years in development (to get it right). Good luck.

Comment: Your solution is already posted here

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size

Comment: Jonathan,  The answer shown in your link assumes unlimited backup space on a hard drive not limited space on a flash, with manual off-loading and therefore pausing of backup, tracking pause marker points and re-insertion of flash, with manual re-mount, but to same mount point.  How does one resolve all these additional issues?  Remember my mounted flash has only 59GB and I am backing up over 280GB of data.

Comment: I was glad to see the "split" option for the tar cmd and would assume by cmd would be:  tar cvzf - ${dir_file_list} | split --bytes=59GB - ${MP}.backup${TDATE}.tar.gz. since I'm building the vars in my BASH script. How then do I loop through this to capture the pause/remount points.  Also I need to log all backed up files and delete them when their backup and transfer are completed.  Assuming I need a way to create log from tar file, then have a script on recieving machine also logging files and pass that log back, via the flash to originating machine for verification.

Comment: Dark Falcon, not everyone has your kind of $$

Comment: I don't even remember how I resolved this. Will have to look and get back to you on it.